# I found everything in the cookies except the mid. Is it encrypted or something like that?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
from requests import get

cookies = {
    'csrftoken': 'zqTulCRLP4j19qZjlz5wxlaPMqgBtAg1',
    'ig_did': '28DDE3CE-4A94-40B5-8E79-F8A723675F1E',
    'ig_nrcb': '1',
    'mid': 'Y1nkwQABAAFiFiPPW5JeJDKiH0ZF',
    'dpr': '2.625'
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.instagram.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'en-CA,en;q=0.9,ar-AE;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-prefers-color-scheme': 'light',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.52',
    'viewport-width': '980'
}

response = get('https://www.instagram.com/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

It was showing me in the cookies without searching the HTML, but it was giving me a response of `"<RequestsCookieJar[]>"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. ([Ask] and the [tour] are good places to start.) What you trying to do? What is `mid`? Is the value you're supplying for `mid` incorrect? If so, how do you know this? It's very unclear what your question is. A good [mre] includes not only code and current output, but *expected* output, and how those differ.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.